# Multiple Calendars Displayed or Value Selected not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery, mobile, datepicker, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-datepicker

Ok I'm using the [jQuery Mobile Framework](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/) and adding the [Experimental Date Picker](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/experiments/ui-datepicker/) but I encounter two results. Following the instructions on the page, this is what I have so far.

Code Efforts #1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $('.hasDatepicker').hide();

    $('#date-of-birth').each(function() {     
        $(this).focus(function() {
            $(this).next().show('fast');
        });

        $(this).blur(function() {               
           $(this).next().hide('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

Now this shows the one calendar (as I would like) but on date selection the date stays the same (it's todays date) and not the date selected.

Code Efforts #2:

```
$(function() {
    $('.hasDatepicker').hide();

    $('#date-of-birth').focus(function() {
        $('.hasDatepicker').show('fast');
    });

    $('#date-of-birth').blur(function() {
        $('.hasDatepicker').hide('fast');
    });
});
```

Now this show multiple calendars (5 to be exact) stacked on top of one another and also if I select the date it works as expected. But I only want one calendar to display.

I would like to combine the two code efforts to get the desired results but nothing really seems to be working.

Here is the HTML

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="date-of-birth">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="date" name="date-of-birth" id="date-of-birth" />                
</div>
```

The `type="date"` is how you call the date picker

Any tips?

Other Stack Links that might shed some light

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947412/datepicker-in-jquery-mobile-is-duplicate-when-is-added-in-a-second-page)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886672/jquery-mobile-override-jquery-ui-datepicker-layout-broken)

UPDATE:

Well this might be the issue but still haven't found a solution.

I using the [Multi-page layout](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/pages/docs-pages.html) option for jQueryMobile, For each page it creates an additional date-picker but it displays them stack on each other and the functionality doesn't work correctly

Comment: What's the point of `$('#date-of-birth').each()` ? ID should be unique. Do you have all the 5 calendars linked to the fields with the same ID? $('#something') can't be expected to return more than one element when you have duplicated IDs. Also - if you duplicate IDs all form enhancements work incorrectly. I've seen that on SO once already.

Comment: it's strange behavior on the calendar duplication, I only have one field that I use for the date-picker. If I just place the code in a function I still get dups, if I use the each() I get one?

Comment: Looks like we didn't understand each other. 1 How many datepickers is there when you remove all your javascript? 2 check out firebug to see if you do have multiple inputs with that id `$('input').each(function(){console.log($(this).attr('id'))})`

Comment: I have one element with that ID and one date-picker on the page, The example HTMl is the only type="date" which calls the date-picker in the mobile framework. If I remove the javascript I get five calendars stacked on each other but the date selection functionality works. If I add the javascript I get one calendar but the date selection functionality doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. I asked this question: [jQuery Mobile -> Override jQuery UI Datepicker -> Layout broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886672/jquery-mobile-override-jquery-ui-datepicker-layout-broken)

It is experimental, but it works. You should not use this

```
$('.hasDatepicker').show('fast');
```

You should add for each datepicker on one site a unique `id` and then write:

$('#uniqueId').show('fast');

I add the IDs inside of the JavaScript file of the datepicker.

Comment: Thanks for your post but it's still not working correctly. I think it's caused by the multi-pae layout shown here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/pages/docs-pages.html I've also updated my question

Comment: This solved my multi-datepicker-display issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947412/datepicker-in-jquery-mobile-is-duplicate-when-is-added-in-a-second-page